# Magento Reindex Products

Tags: magento, reindex

Recently I ran into a problem regarding Re-index in Magento.

My store has around 40,000 products and If I change a status of a single product, changes are not reflected on frontend as it needs reindexing of all Indexes.

Moreoever reindexing takes a hell lot of time (around an hour) and I am thinking of a permanent issue.

What does "Save on Update" mode in Reindex specifies ? Does it help in reindexing while saving the product ?

Whats the difference between manual update and update on save ?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "**Update On Save**" re-indexing mode, it will do re-index on the fly for that single product you have saved.

Comment: Could you pls let me know whats re-index on fly and will it reindex the last product edited or updated and what about other prodcuts ?Will it reflect the changes too? Moreover saving the product will take time if mode set id Update on Save ?? Pls help..

Comment: I mean that index will not take a lot of time, since it will be for a single product, you can try it if you edit a product from the Admin Panel and click Save magento will save & reindex that single product.

I'm talking about Magento CE 1.7.x, I don't know this could work on previous versions.

By the way 40K products is not a big issue, I did it with a store have 500K+ products and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean "**Update on Save**" when you say save on update, also called as "**realtime**" mode which **`triggers the re-indexing of product data`** every time the product has been saved / updated.

Basically in Magento there are only two modes of re-indexing "**Update on Save**" (Realtime) and "**Manual**". Their names speak their mode of behavior quite clearly.

In your case, as you have huge amount of products in your store, do the re-indexing through Magento SHELL commands like the following which in turn saves you a lot of time.

SSH to your store and go to shell folder inside your magento root and re-index one by one or all in one shot

```
    php indexer.php --reindex  catalog_product_flat
    php indexer.php reindexall
```

Comment: Make sure i mentioned in my answer "catalog_product_flat" just for an example if you have enabled flat products in your store. Fundamentally the right index type would be "catalog_product_attribute", "catalog_product_price" or "catalog_category_product". . Try this before you re-index php indexer.php --status

Comment: I have reindexed via shell to and it still takes a lot of time to perform the action. I need to know what does Update on Save does ? Will it reindex the last product changed/edited and reflect latest changes on frontend ?

Answer (score 0):

The magento manual (http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/index-management-manual.html)

States:

Set Actions to “Reindex Data.”

Its too bad the options are not available!  Do you see those options in your admin pages?  If not, is there a reason why it might not show up?

I would like to do update on save, but this is not really practical.  I imported a large number of products from CSV.

I tried running the re-indexer from the command line, but by shell directory is missing.

[magento missing shell directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794663/magento-missing-shell-directory)

Well, it looks like I am fresh out of ideas!  Maybe I should just pay Varien to run Magento Enterprise for me.  Afterall, re-indexing is a bit complicated, isn't it?