# Auto reindex mode Magento

Tags: magento, reindex

I'm new in magento, i turned index mode to update on save. I thought it would reindex on any update, but on some operations he still asks to reindex. I searched the internet, but i couldn't confirm it for sure. It seems that it is really necessary to set a cron job to reindex. Does index mode update on save reindex on any update or operation?

Comment: This question would be better asked on [magento.se]

Comment: Check this out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174649/magento-reindex-products