# magento missing shell directory

Tags: php, shell, magento, logging

I was trying to run shell/log.php to clean the logs on one of our magento websites and it's missing. I'm wondering why it's missing and how to fix that. here's the bash output:

```
[root@example.com www]# php shell/log.php
Could not open input file: shell/log.php
```

Comment: it doesnt exist. shell directory is missing completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full command is

```
*php -f shell/log.php clean*
```

or you can clean logs via phpMyAdmin or another one. Just empty following tables:

```
dataflow_batch_export
dataflow_batch_import
log_customer
log_quote
log_summary
log_summary_type
log_url
log_url_info
log_visitor
log_visitor_info
log_visitor_online
report_viewed_product_index
report_compared_product_index
```

Comment: the root directory doesnt have a shell directory at all, so i cant run that command. however, i could clear the database manually as suggested. so the answer was accepted. thanks